# mdMenu not closing when clicking outside of it

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

$mdMenu.close() not working in angularjs. md-menu will close when click the option. Menu is not closing When click outside of it.

```
<md-menu md-offset='120 60' md-position-mode='target-right target'>
    <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()" ng-href="">Manage List</md-button>
    <md-menu-content width="3" class="menu-content" ng-mouseleave="$mdMenu.close()">
        <md-menu-item>
            <md-button ng-click="open()">Menu 1</md-button>
        </md-menu-item>
        <md-menu-item>
            <md-button ng-click="open()">Menu 2</md-button>
        </md-menu-item>
        <md-menu-item>
            <md-button ng-click="open()">Menu 3</md-button>
        </md-menu-item>
    </md-menu-content>
</md-menu>
```

Comment: seems to work just fine here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/bPsgF4elFUalhvJCdRsO?p=preview

Comment: You should change `$mdOpenMenu()` to `$mdMenu.open()` as it's deprecated.